# WPF How to set style on RadioButton?

Tags: c#, wpf, radio-button

I have this code:

```
                 <GroupBox Grid.Column="1" BorderThickness="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                    <ItemsControl FontWeight="Normal" 
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AvailableTipologieDifficolta}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <RadioButton
                                  Content="{Binding Path=DisplayName}"
                                  IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected}"
                                  GroupName="Feedback"
                                  Margin="10,3.5"
                                  Style="{StaticResource RadioButtonTemplate}"
                                />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </GroupBox>
```

This is the style of RadioButton:

```
        <Style TargetType="RadioButton" x:Key="RadioButtonTemplate">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton">
                        <RadioButton Foreground="White" FontSize="20">
                            <ContentPresenter/>
                        </RadioButton>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

So when I try to run my code I have this:

o Opzione 1
o Opzione 2

I can to select every option but it is not possible. If I delete this code Style="{StaticResource RadioButtonTemplate}" I can to select one option.

Can we help me?

Comment: *Can we help me?*... use words to explain your problem and your desired outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you wrap `RadioButton` in `RadioButton` when you create template like that. Inner `RadioButton` is not linked to outer `RadioButton`. You don't need to change template for what you want to do just use 2 `Setters` for `Foreground` and `FontSize`

```
<Style TargetType="RadioButton" x:Key="RadioButtonTemplate">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"/>
</Style>
```